# How to match the ' or " with ' or " in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

The following regular expression is used to extract the URL link from a page:

```
LINK_REGEX = re.compile("<a [^>]*href=['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>")
```

**Question1**> How to represent the following string? I mismatch the ' and " in purpose

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com'>
```

I have tried the following statements and none work for me.

```
>>> page = '<a href="http://www.yahoo.com\'>'
>>> page
'<a href="http://www.yahoo.com\'>'
>>> page = '<a href="http://www.yahoo.com''>'
>>> page
'<a href="http://www.yahoo.com>'
```

**Question2**> Based on my understanding, by design, the LINK_REGEX will match above link although this is not desirable. So how can I modify the regular expression so that it enforces the matching of ' with ' or " with ".

Comment: You could just simplify your life by using two more simple regexes...

Comment: Triple-quotes are your friend here. Try: `page = """<a href="http://www.yahoo.com'>"""`.

Comment: It might not be an issue if you use xml parser to grab the info.

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1, your first approach works.

```
>>> page = '<a href="http://www.yahoo.com\'>'
>>> len(page)
31
>>> page
'<a href="http://www.yahoo.com\'>'
>>> page[-1]
'>'
>>> page[-2]
"'"
>>> page[-3]
'm'
```

Answer (score 1):

(I'd post this as a comment if I had the privilege.)

If you're trying to parse HTML, it is highly recommended that you do not use regex. You'll be saving yourself lots of hassle and problems if you use an HTML parsing module like BeautifulSoup or lxml.html.

Second, pretty much every time you're using regex, be sure to prepend `r` to your string, like so:

`LINK_REGEX = re.compile(r"<a [^>]*href=['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>")`

This will ensure things are escaped properly.

If you definitely need to use regex though, "9000's" answer will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`['"]` will match `'` or `"`.

`(['"]).+\1` will match a quoted string with matcing quotes. The expression in parens (match group) will match a single or double quote, and `\1` will match whatever the first match group have matched (this is called 'backreference').

**Note** that the quotes are *not* escaped in any way in the expressions to make them more readable. Your regex strings may need to escape at least one kind of quotes.

Comment: Hmm, consider `<a href="foo" bar="baz">` ;)

Comment: @fge: non-greedy qualifiers to the rescue! Use `+?` instead of plain `+`. The point of the question was in matching the same quote; the rest is left as an exercise :)

Comment: Hmm, consider `<a href="foo' bar='baz">` ;)

Comment: @AlanMoore: AFAIK real browsers only handle matching quotes. Consider `<input text="O'Reilly">`.

Comment: The question was how to *enforce* correct pairing of quotes with a regex--and the answer is "You can't."  Whether you use greedy or non-greedy quantifiers, it will keep going until it finds another quote to match the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use two regexes:

```
<a\s*[^>]*href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>  # double quoted strings
<a\s*[^>]*href='([^']+)'[^>]*>  # single quoted strings
```

The content of `href` will then be in the second group.

Comment: What about: `<a href="this won't match">`?

Comment: Yeah, which is why I first commented that it would be easier to use two regexes...

Comment: In your original back-reference version, I think you could have used `(.+?)` instead of `([^"']+)`, ftw ;-)